# Из struct в class и чтение с файла C++

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Была некая структура:

```
typedef struct 
{
  int number;
  int numer2;
  float number3;
  TDateTime t_n;  
  float frez[4];
}; test1
```

Далее была следующая запись :

```
test1 t[8];
```

Ну и код чтения из бинарного файла:

```
ReadFile(f_per, &t, 104, &writed_per, NULL);
```

Не очень мне нравилось такое решение, да и практика нужна, решил заменить структуру на класс:

```
class Transhipment
{
private:
    int number;
    int number2;
    float number3;
    double t_n;  
    float frez[4];
public:
    void set_Number1(int);
    int get_Number1();
    void set_Number2(int);
    int get_Number2();
    void set_Number3(float);
    float get_Number3();
    void set_Time_new(double);
    double get_Time_new();
    void set_Frez(float[4]);
    float get_Frez();
}
```

Далее столкнулся с проблемой чтения данных и передачей в свойства.

```
Transhipment per;
int test;
fileShaft->Position = (0);
fileShaft->Read(&test, 4);    //832
per.set_Number(test);
```

данные я конечно получил какие нужно, но мне нужно все 832 байта раскидать автоматически а не вручную, как я себе сейчас это представляю :

```
 fileShaft->Position = (4); 
 fileShaft->Read(&test2, 4);    //832
 per.set_Number2(test2);
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как правильно работать с классом. Спасибо

Comment: Мало конкретики. И причем тут Builder?

Comment: @Sublihim конкретно хочу понять как прочитать данные из файла и раскидать их в нужные свойства класса, для дальнейшей работы с числами. Не смещаясь по позициям, как я показал в примере выше. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: так и используйте теперь свой класс вместо структуры точно так же ) `Transhipment t[8]; ReadFile(f_per, &t, 104, &writed_per, NULL);`

Comment: @Sublihim Оформите как ответ, я закрою тему. Большое вам спасибо, почему-то я сразу не подумал что так можно )))

Comment: Оформил как ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как у вас класс не имеет ни виртуальных функций, ни виртуального наследования, то вы можете использовать ваш класс, так же, как и предыдущую структуру.

```
class Transhipment
{
private:
    int number;
    int number2;
    float number3;
    double t_n;  
    float frez[4];
public:
    void set_Number1(int);
    int get_Number1();
    void set_Number2(int);
    int get_Number2();
    void set_Number3(float);
    float get_Number3();
    void set_Time_new(double);
    double get_Time_new();
    void set_Frez(float[4]);
    float get_Frez();
}

// Соответственно:
Transhipment t[8]; 
ReadFile(f_per, &t, 104, &writed_per, NULL);
```